# how to limit form grid to one response per column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am building a google form with apps script and am unable to duplicate functionality found in the builder.

I cannot find methods to set the option on a GridItem called
"limit to one response per column"
or
"shuffle row order"

both which are found in an advanced tab at the bottom of the grid edit block.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the Forms service to programmatically build a form - you weren't clear in your question.

Those advanced settings have not been exposed through the Google Apps Script [Forms service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms). Since there's no other API for Forms, your only recourse is to request an API extension. [Issue 6393](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6393) is asking for it now, and you can star that issue to add your vote for it.

There is one relevant open issue, [Issue 3654](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3654), which is an enhancement-request for control over the number of selections allowed per line in a griditem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this and following the [Google Apps Scripts guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-validation) here was successful for me. You have to add your own help text that you want to appear.

```
.setHelpText('Limit to one response per column');
```

Here's the info from the link:

```
// Add a grid item to a form and require one response per column.
 var gridItem = form.addGridItem();
 gridItem.setTitle('Rate your interests')
   .setRows(['Cars', 'Computers', 'Celebrities'])
   .setColumns(['Boring', 'So-so', 'Interesting']);
 var gridValidation = FormApp.createGridValidation()
   .setHelpText(“Select one item per column.”)
   .requireLimitOneResponsePerColumn()
   .build();
 gridItem.setValidation(gridValidation);
```